# Windows 10 1809 Brightness Settings Disappeared

Tags: windows, windows-10, brightness, display-settings

After manually installing the Windows 10 1809 update, the display brightness option disappeared from my battery panel, the mobility center and the power options in the control panel. It's still present in both the settings app and the action center.

In the power plan settings, I can't set options like the dimmed display brightness and daptive brightness either. They're gone.

My laptop has Intel UHD 630 graphics and an NVidia GTX 1060 Max-Q. I tried reinstalling the Intel driver and removing the display using the Device Manager (a fix which seemingly works for Windows 7), but to no avail.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Some screenshots:

[image: Battery panel without brightness setting]
[image: Action center with brightness setting]
[image: Power plan settings without brightness setting]
[image: Display settings with brightness setting]

UPDATE:
I've done a full Windows re-install, which brought all the settings back. After installing the 1809 update, however, the settings disappeared again. It seems to be a bug.

Comment: You really should provide a translations for your screenshot, or switch your interface to English, for the purposes of getting the screenshots.

Comment: @Ramhound Fixed them!

Comment: How many places do you need to be able to access the setting?

Comment: @fixer1234 I at least need to have the setting in the advanced power plan settings. I can't set options like adaptive brightness now.

Comment: You wrote "It's still present in both the settings app and the action center", so it sounded like it was still accessible.  Can you edit the question to clarify that?  Operating systems do periodically tweak the locations of things, so if a feature used to be accessible in a bunch of places and is now accessible in fewer, you just access it where it currently is.  If you're saying it completely disappeared, that's a different case.

Comment: **1.** https://github.com/blackholeearth/Win10_BrightnessSlider/releases adds a proper brightness slider to the notification area (1-click access). 

**2.** Alternatively, move the 25% increment brightness button in the Action Center (lower right) to the top row for constant visibility (through *Metro Settings>System>Notifications & Actions*).

[Forum thread...](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/brightness-slider-gone-windows-10/3560b0bb-526e-47d1-961a-88b3db2e6b1f)